# python: 500 error using json.load() in cherrypy

Tags: python, json, load, cherrypy

My code runs fine locally but I get a 500 error with the webhost I'm using. The problem seems to come from the line

```
js = json.load(data)
```

in the search method. Is there something in the cherrypy config that I'm missing? Any thoughts?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.2
import cherrypy
import json
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlopen

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):

            a_query = Query()
            text = a_query.search()

            return '''<html>
            Welcome to Spoti.py! %s
            </html>''' %text

class Query():

    def __init__(self):
        self.qstring = '''if i can't'''

    def space_to_plus(self):
        self.qstring = self.qstring.replace(' ', '+')    

    def search(self):
        self.space_to_plus()
        url = 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=' + self.qstring
        data = urlopen(url)
        js = json.load(data)
        return self.qstring


cherrypy.config.update({
    'environment': 'production',
    'log.screen': False,
    'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port': 15083,
})

cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.on': True})

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: have you tried to just open link in browser? Server error 500 is internal server error - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error, looks like it has nothing to do with json or cherrypy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems json.loads() is expecting a unicode object when bytes are given. Try this:

```
data = urlopen(url).read()
js = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: With those changes, it works for me.

You might want to remove the config entry `'environment': 'production'` and post a stack trace.

Comment: Thanks! actually u really helped me figure out the problem! In the end I needed to use:
        data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        raw_data = data.read()
        info_dict = json.loads(raw_data.decode('utf-8'))